# Best Practices on how to maintain images on S3 with the same name and invalidate the cache

Tags: amazon-s3, http-headers, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I would like to understand if there are any best practices on how to maintain images on S3 and use cloudfront to access them. The reason why am asking this question is because of how S3 and cloudfront work together.

I upload an image, set an expiry using the meta tags on S3 and try to use the cloudfront URL I get the desired image. The problem is when I try to update the same image and it does not immediately reflect until the set expiry on the meta tags in met.

Is there a good way to get the latest image if there is a change on S3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell CloudFront that the file it has cached has changed, so that it will get the updated version from S3. To do this  you [invalidate](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/08/31/cloudfront-adds-invalidation-feature/) the file on CloudFront.  Then the next time that file is requested, CloudFront will go back to S3 to get the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

While you can use Cloudfront's invalidate feature, I believe that has a propagation delay so it could be an issue if you make drastic changes to images/css/js.

We went through a similar progression with making sure changes always propagate immediately before getting on Cloudfront and then again after getting on Cloudfront. I'm assuming many others are as well so coinciding with some more upgrades/updates to the script I wrote, I decided to let other people use it ([more history here](https://github.com/alltuition/version-tags#history)!)

The script is hosted here with: https://github.com/alltuition/version-tags

Basically it's a Python OR Django script that uses Linux commands and git history to figure out what file modifications were made to media files, then uses sed to update all references to a different path for modified files. (files must be served from a server that allows you to use wildcard aliases (the README provides instructions for Nginx, Apache and Django dev server.))

All changes to media files are updated in user's browsers immediately since the first person that gets the first modified html page requests a url that is not in Cloudfront's cache so Cloudfront goes and grabs the new version of the file. This also means that you can set all of your media files to never expire.